# Calculation without calculator

Tags: calculus

> Find the value of $\sqrt{5}$ without using calculator.

I've tried using iteration, but it doesn't converge easily.
Pls help me out.

Comment: Which iteration did you try?

Comment: Newton-raphson Iteration

Comment: $\sqrt 5$ has a non periodic decimal expansion. What do you mean by *find the value*?

Answer (score 5):

For an *approximation*
$$\sqrt 5=\sqrt{4+1}=2\sqrt{1+\frac14}$$ Now, using the binomial expansion or Taylor series
$$\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{x^3}{16}-\frac{5 x^4}{128}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ Replace $x$ by $\frac14$ to get 
$$\sqrt 5\approx \frac{36635}{16384}\approx 2.23602$$ while the "exact" value would be $\approx 2.23607$.

Even simpler, consider the $[2,2]$ Padé approximant
$$\sqrt{1+x}=\frac{1+\frac{5 }{4}x+\frac{5 }{16}x^2}{1+\frac{3 }{4}x+\frac{1}{16}x^2}$$ which gives 
$$\sqrt 5\approx \frac{682}{305}\approx 2.23607$$

**Edit**

Some other answers used Newton method. Using Halley method, the very first iterate would be $\frac {38}{17}\approx 2.23529$ which is not too bad. The second one would be $\frac{219602}{98209}\approx 2.23607$.

What could also be interesting is to consider
$$\sqrt[n]{k^n+a}=k\sqrt[n]{1+\frac a{k^n}}$$ and using the $[2,2]$ Padé approximant, we should get, as an approximation
$$\sqrt[n]{k^n+a}=\frac{1+\left(1+\frac{1}{2 n}\right) \epsilon +\frac{\left(2 n^2+3 n+1\right) }{12 n^2}\epsilon
   ^2 } {1+\left(1-\frac{1}{2 n}\right) \epsilon +\frac{\left(2 n^2-3 n+1\right) }{12 n^2} \epsilon
   ^2}\qquad \text{using}\qquad \epsilon=\frac a {k^n}$$

Comment: I'd use an expansion of $\sqrt{4+x}$

Comment: Pade approximation looks much simpler and very accurate. +1 for mentioning it here.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh. One of my passions ! You could not believe the number of things I have been able to do with it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In order to approximate $\sqrt{a}$ for $a>0$ by using an iterative method, consider, for $x>0$, the function
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\frac{a}{x}\right)$$
that is the average of $x$ and $a/x$. Note that if $x<\sqrt{a}$ then $a/x>\sqrt{a}$ and vice versa.
For $a=5$ and starting from $2$ we obtain after 3 iteration
$$9/4,\quad 161/72,\quad 51841/23184\approx 2.236067978$$
which is a quite good approximation of $\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: A variation on this for $\sqrt A\;$  is $g(x)=x-\frac {2x(x^2-A)}{3x^2+A}.$  If $x^2-A=F$ then $(g(x)-A)^2=\frac {F^3}{(3x^2+A)^2}.$

Answer (score 1):

$$y = f(x) = \sqrt x$$

$$\Delta y = f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)$$

$$x = 2.2^2=4.84, \Delta x = 0.16$$

$$\implies \Delta y = \sqrt 5 - 2.2$$

$$\Delta y=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\Delta x \approx \frac{dy}{dx}\Delta x=\frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}\Delta x=\frac {1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2.2}\times 0.16\approx0.036$$

$$\implies \sqrt 5 \approx 2.236$$

Answer (score 1):

$9^2-5\times4^2= 81-80=1$ is a solution of the Brahmagupta equation $ x^2-5y^2=1$. So the first approximate solution is $9/4$. To get the next approximation from the first (a/b)  for $x^2-db^2=1$ use the substitution $$(a/b)\longrightarrow (1+2db^2)/2ab= (1+10b^2)/2ab,$$ which yields $161/72$. You can iterate getting more accuracy. Note that we are already very close:  $(161/72)^2=5.000192901234568$. Actually Newton-Raphson for this equation yields the same value as Brahmagupta's formula. (algebraic methods giving numerical approximation!)

Answer (score 1):

**With pen and paper only**, one can compute digits of square roots of small integers one by one using algorithm below.
I have done that for $\sqrt{3}$ and get $1.73205080756887\ldots$ while I'm in high school.

> 1. $p \leftarrow \verb/input/ \in \{1, \ldots, 99\}\\
>        n \leftarrow \verb/input/ \in \mathbb{Z}_{+},\\
>        q \leftarrow 0.$
> 2. $r \leftarrow \max\big\{ t \in \{ 0, \ldots, 9 \} : 20qt +t^2 \le p \big\},\\
>        s \leftarrow (20q + r)r,\\
>        q \leftarrow 10q + r,\\
>        p \leftarrow 100(p-s),\\
>        n \leftarrow n-1.$
> 3. $\verb/if/(( p \ne 0 ) \land (n > 0)) \verb/ goto / \text{step} 2.$
> 4. $q \rightarrow \verb/output/$.

The basic idea of above algorithm goes like this. In an expression like

$$\sqrt{p} = q\quad\text{ where }\quad q = (q_0.q_1q_2q_3\cdots)_{10}$$

If we know the decimal representation of $q$ up to $k$-digits $(q_0.q_1,\ldots,q_{k})_{10}$, the next digit $q_{k+1}$ will be the largest $r$ which satisfy:
$$p \ge (q_0.q_1\ldots,q_{k} r)_{10}^2$$
In above algorithm, we have keep the partial differences
$p - (q_0.q_1\ldots,q_{k})_{10}^2$ to simplify comparison and multiply everything by suitable powers of $10$ to allow us work within integers.

As an example, I write a program to implement above algorithm for $q = 5, n = 10$.
Following is the output:

```
[ 0] p <- 5
     q <- 0
     n <- 10
[ 1] r: 2 p: 100          = 100*(5-4)
          q:  2           = 10*0 + 2
[ 2] r: 2 p: 1600         = 100*(100-84)
          q:  22          = 10*2 + 2
[ 3] r: 3 p: 27100        = 100*(1600-1329)
          q:  223         = 10*22 + 3
[ 4] r: 6 p: 30400        = 100*(27100-26796)
          q:  2236        = 10*223 + 6
[ 5] r: 0 p: 3040000      = 100*(30400-0)
          q:  22360       = 10*2236 + 0
[ 6] r: 6 p: 35676400     = 100*(3040000-2683236)
          q:  223606      = 10*22360 + 6
[ 7] r: 7 p: 437151100    = 100*(35676400-31304889)
          q:  2236067     = 10*223606 + 7
[ 8] r: 9 p: 3465895900   = 100*(437151100-402492141)
          q:  22360679    = 10*2236067 + 9
[ 9] r: 7 p: 33540079100  = 100*(3465895900-3130495109)
          q:  223606797   = 10*22360679 + 7
[10] r: 7 p: 223512747100 = 100*(33540079100-31304951629)
          q:  2236067977  = 10*223606797 + 7
result: 2236067977
```

The last line means up to $9$ decimal places, the decimal representation of $\sqrt{5}$ is $2.236067977\ldots$.

Comment: This is really nice ! Thanks for providing such an answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is adding their favourite approximation method for quadratic irrationals, so continued fractions, why not?

$$
\begin{align}
x &= \sqrt5\\
x^2 &= 5\\
x^2-1 &= (x-1)(x+1)=4\\
x-1 &=\frac{4}{1+x}\\
x &= 1 + \frac{4}{1+x}\\
x &= 1 + \frac{4}{1+1+\frac{4}{1+x}}=1 + \frac{4}{2+\frac{4}{1+x}}\\
x &=1+{\cfrac {4}{2+{\cfrac {4}{2+{\cfrac {4}{2+{\cfrac {4}{2+\ddots }}}}}}}}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

By Newton's Method, since $\sqrt5$ is the root of $f(x)=x^2-5=0$, we perform the process

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}=x_n-\frac{x_n^2-5}{2x_n}=\frac{x_n}{2}+\frac5{2x_n}$$
where $x_n$ is the $n^{th}$ approaxiamtion.

Taking a reasonable approximation of $x_0=2$, we have

$$x_1=1+\frac54=\frac94$$
$$x_2=\frac98+\frac{10}9=\frac{161}{72}$$
$$x_3=\frac{161}{144}+\frac{180}{161}=\frac{51841}{23184}\approx2.23$$

which is a fair approximation since  $2.23^2=4.9729$

Comment: Come on! $51841/23184$ without calculator???

Comment: @Raffaele I originally want to show how close (of my limited knowledge on) this method can be, so just give the numerical value to $x_3$. I admit it may be an inefficient method, but even if $\frac{51841}{23184}\approx 2.23$, which only needs 3 division, it gives the close value $2.23^2=4.9729$. I fixed my answer with reference to your comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Iteration without a calculator is a nightmare! How many decimals do you want? $$\sqrt{x+4}=2+\frac{x}{4}-\frac{x^2}{64}++\frac{x^3}{512}+O(x^4)$$ for $x=1$ gives $\sqrt{5}\approx \dfrac{1145}{512}$ with three exact decimals

$1145/512$ by hand is not amusing but one can work it out

```
1145    512
        2.236
1024
 1210
 1024
  1860
  1536
   3240
   3072
    168
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to calculate the root of a positive number $M$.

Assume $x=\sqrt M$,then

$f(x)=x^2-M=0$.

Now use the Newton-Raphson Method.Newton-Raphson method  For this equation is given by
\begin{equation}
x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}
\end{equation}